# Sum of a count field to get overall total

Tags: php, count, sum

I am very new to this and am looking for some help. I am replicating a report in my current system with the following code.

```
    <?php
     foreach ($possibleSanctionsAssociativeArray as $currentSanction => $currentSanctionDetailsArray)
    {   
        $tableHeadersArray = array ('Home Office',' Total');

        $query = "SELECT home_office, COUNT(file_id) FROM cases WHERE ".$currentSanction."='Yes' and ($refdate>='$begindate' AND $refdate<='$enddate') GROUP BY home_office";

        $title = "<p class='report_title'> <b>".getSanctionDescriptiveName($currentSanction)."</b>";
        simpleStatTable($query, $tableHeadersArray, $title);
    }
    ?>
```

It displays a Table with two columns and two rows:

```
HOME OFFICE    |    Total

OJA            |     82

ORL            |    634
```

I would like it to display a third row that says "OVERALL TOTAL | 716"

I have tried several solutions with no luck, I think I am struggling with the sum of a count field, then displaying the count.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: what is `simpleStatTable()` ?

Comment: @Bala R You're probably going to smack yourself when you read this - but i am not exactly certain, I think it is a set up for a table. I didn't write this code, but i have the task of manipulating it. Top that off with the fact that I have a very basic knowledge of MySQL/PHP (as if you didn't know that by my initial question) and am learning as I go. Not ideal I know but sometimes we gotta do what we gotta do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the question at first. This should work:

```
$query = "SELECT home_office, COUNT(file_id) FROM cases
            WHERE ".$currentSanction."='Yes' and ($refdate>='$begindate' AND $refdate<='$enddate')
            GROUP BY home_office
          UNION
          SELECT 'Overall Total' AS home_office, COUNT(file_id) FROM cases
            WHERE ".$currentSanction."='Yes' and ($refdate>='$begindate' AND $refdate<='$enddate');";
```

Comment: Thanks  for the input but I need to display the break down and the over all total.

Comment: @TheTwo Updated. This should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Again...Tried it - there are still some display issues (repeats home office name in overall totals row) but other than that it works. I will play around some more but I need to go to an appointment. Thanks So Much!

Comment: @TheTwo: My mistake: it should be `'Total' as 'home_office'` (fixed)

Comment: Thanks again!, not i need to figure out the same issue but with more complex code. :)

Answer (score 5):

As it was said, never use a query inside a loop unless it's really needed. About getting the whole sum, in case you're using MySQL, you could use the [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this as well...the table stops displaying all together. I guess I need to rework the entire code with a join statement as was mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about the performance implications of this one, but you could try

`SELECT SUM(totals) FROM (SELECT home_office, COUNT(file_id) AS totals FROM cases WHERE ".$currentSanction."='Yes' and ($refdate>='$begindate' AND $refdate<='$enddate') GROUP BY home_office AS counts_table)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$countTotal = 0;
foreach() {
   $query = /*...*/
   $row = mysql_fetch_*($query);
   $countTotal += $row['count'];   
}

echo $countTotal;
```

Anyway never put a query inside a loop, use Join instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it has stopped displaying the table all together. Like I said, I'm new to this and am trying to learn as I go. I have seen the join information but how do you  write one with one table?